# putting two files into one

Tags: csh

I have two files: one.txt with 108 lines and 10 columns and two.txt with 1 line and one column. I want to add the number in two.txt to each line of one.txt as the 11th column. What is the best option?
I tried with `paste one.txt two.txt | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' > uj.txt` but only the first line got the number of two.txt

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add some sample lines from both of your files (and the desired outcome) so we have something to try and play with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to replicate the (single) content of `two.txt` after each line of `one.txt`. Given

```
$ cat one.txt 
abc def
ghi jkl
mno pqr
```

and

```
$ cat two.txt 
23
```

then modifying your attempted solution slightly:

```
$ paste one.txt two.txt | awk 'NR==1 {x = $NF} NR>1 {$(NF+1) = x} 1'
abc def 23
ghi jkl 23
mno pqr 23
```

Alternatively with `awk` only:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {x = $1; next} {print $0, x}' two.txt one.txt 
abc def 23
ghi jkl 23
mno pqr 23
```